# how to define id_pst in my action comment of yii2?

Tags: yii2

I have create a action comment like this:

```
public function actionComment($id) 
{
    $text = CommentModel::find($id)->where(true)->all();
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $text = new CommentModel(); 
        $text->name=$_POST['name'];
        $text->comment=$_POST['comment'];
        $text->i_post=$_POST['id_post'];
        $text->save();
        $this->redirect('comment',array('id'=>$text->id));
    }
    
    return $this->render('comment',array("text"=>$text));
}
```

and comment view is:

```
<h2>List of all comments:</h2>

<?php 
foreach($text as $text[0]){
echo "name"." ".":"." ".$text[0]->name."<br>" ;
echo "comment"." ".":"." ".$text[0]->comment."<br>";
?>
```

my comment model is:

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'name' => 'Name',
        'comment' => 'Comment',
        'id-post' => 'Id Post',
    ];
}
```

how should i define id_pst in my project to each post has sepecific comment??

Comment: I personally don't get what you are trying to achieve. Please add more details.

Comment: I wana make a simple blog which each post can have comments.but in my php code all of my posts have same comments. It doesnt recognize which comment is belongs to which post.

Comment: maybe you should first look at your 'IDs' as you use `id_pst`, `id-post`, `i_post`, `id_post` and `id` somewhere around you code. I guess something will be wrong here. And you do not mention the Post anywhere, only the comments. How can we see the problem, if you do not give any output and also only a little irrelevant info of your model - `attributesLabels`!?  - this does not help much

Comment: Show your output, and provide the example output you want.

Comment: It also appears you have not provided all of the relevant code. For instance, how is the id generated?